# Ubuntu 12.04 gnome classic problem - multiple top and bottom bars

Tags: 12.04, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, with gnome classic. I was using it with no problem. Then after I logged in once I saw 4 bars at the top of the screen and 4 at the bottom instead of 1.  How can I fix it? I tried removing and reinstalling gnome-panel. But it didn't work.

Comment: Can't you right click at the panel and delete it?

Comment: No, there is no right click menu at the panel.

Comment: Neither can you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right click?

Comment: That worked !!!

Comment: ... Great!!! :-) ...

Comment: Ah internet, is there nothing you can't help me with? I was plagued by this for a month (and had stopped using the laptop with this symptom)... when 1 search on AskUbuntu fixed the issue in 2 minutes.

Comment: Had this issue in 12.10 as well. Alt-Right click helped me solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alt+Super+Right Click is what works for me :D

Comment: alt + right_click works too